# Is "learnable" a valid English word?

Tags: word-usage, neologisms

In my thesis I am quoting a passage from a paper in which the author* used the word "learnable" in the sense of something that is easy to be learned.

I have searched for the word in both the Merriam-Webster and the Cambridge English online dictionaries, but didn't find it there. Nevertheless, this word seems to be used quite a lot in many scientific papers, it returns 775,000 results on Google and [a lot of occurrences in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=learnable&title=Special%3aSearch&go=Go).

So I ask: is this a valid word in English or, perhaps, just a neologism?

<sup>* he is from the University of South Florida and has a common American name - just in case somebody finds this relevant</sup>

Comment: Pay no attention whatever to that 776,000 Google gives you: it's not a count, just a guess. In fact, if you track down to the end of the hits Google will only show you 880, and some of those are merely adjacent occurrences of *learn* and *able*.

Comment: Its in Collins... [learn](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/learn)

Comment: Is it pronounceable?  Is it formed according to established rules?  Most importantly, is the meaning clear to your everyday English speaker?  If all answers are "yes", then it's a word.  :)  Whether someone will think it sounds odd, is a whole other question.

Comment: The analogy with the word "teachable" suggests that "learnable" is perfectly valid. There was a 1984 MIT paper [A theory of the learnable](http://web.mit.edu/6.435/www/Valiant84.pdf) which suggests it's not even all that new… I'd say that yes, it is a valid English word.

Comment: It's in the 1913 edition of Webster's Dictionary as well: ["a. Such as can be learned."](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=learnable&use1913=on&use1828=on).

Comment: Not only did Valiant use the term in the 1984 paper mentioned by @Floris, but that paper started a whole field on the mathematical theory of learnability. Within theoretical computer science, it's definitely a word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[*Learnable*](http://archive.org/stream/oed6aarch#page/n169/mode/2up) has been in use at least since the early 17th century.

By and large, when you find that an ordinary suffix has been attached to a word of the sort it is ordinarily attached to, and that the resulting sense is exactly that which such compounds ordinarily bear, it’s a legitimate word regardless of whether it appears in a dictionary. That’s what linguists mean when they say that a suffix or idiomatic pattern is ‘productive’: that it is regularly used to create valid new words or phrases.

(And observe, please, that calling a term a *neologism* does not ‘invalidate’ it, whatever that might mean. To say a word is ‘valid’ can only mean that it is used and understood within its particular context or register, regardless of its age.)

In this case, *-able* is regularly attachable to any transitive *VERB* to express the meaning *capable of being VERBed*. *Learn* is a transitive verb, and *learnable* means *capable of being learned*. That’s all it takes.

Comment: Thank you for the note about the neologism. Very useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course *learnable* is a word. Perhaps most people tend to use the term *teachable* instead of learnable; they do not seem to understand that teachable refers to someone who *can be taught*, and not something that can teach us anything. It's surprising how poorly Americans use the English language.